# Jquery mobile: page size not refreshed after adding an element

Tags: jquery-mobile

So, what I am struggling with is that I "loose" parts of the page after adding elements in the contens section of my jquery mobile page. I am then not able to scroll down to see the bottom of the page.

I have tried several solutions so far.

```
$('#<pageId>').trigger('create'); after adding the elements.
```

And placing

```
$.support.touchOverflow = true;
$.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
```

in the pageinit event.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Regards

Edit:

I have buttons that show/hide some divs as well. Clicking on these updates the page size, and I am then able to scroll the whole way down.

The problem is experienced using phonegap on android simulator/device

Comment: `.trigger('create');` typically would do what you want. Could you provide a code sample (jsFiddle) to demonstrate?

Comment: @Ryan Bates - Thanks for your response. I tested the code in JSFiddle and it does not produce the same error. Worth mentioning that I am experiencing this using phonegap, running on a android simulator and on the actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for some reason this did not work out of the box for android. But I came up with another solution.

After adding elements to the DOM i set the body size to the div containing all elements.

```
$('body').css({'height' : $('#<div id>').height()});
```

Hope someone saves time :-)